# Back to the previous binding of the list box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I had few reading about how to navigate between pages and using the back button.

What I try to do actually is implementing one of my button on the tap event to go back to the previous list box items.

I mean, I bind folders on my listbox. When I click on an item I load the subfolders so the itemssource is changing.

How can I , when i click on the back button, display the previous itemsource of the listbox ?

Should I use history ? Everything is on the same page, so i definitly can't use this navigate method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into the OnBackKeyPress method and alter the ItemsSource, you need to make sure that you can exit your application sucessfully if you went down this route :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Yes but how can i take the previous item source ?

Comment: Prior to changing the ItemsSource, record what the ItemsSource is in another variable, then use this variable to restore the ItemsSource.